# Central Limit Theorem for Dependent Variables

Tags: probability-theory

I am interested in expanding a physics model where I use the fact that, when I consider no interaction between $N$

particles, i.e. the random variables are independent, I can use the results of the well-known Central Limit Theorem (CLT) to assure they will follow a normal distribution.

I would like now to introduce 'some interactions' to prove that, in deed, under certain conditions the same results for the model are achieved.

In order to prove that I am looking for a Dependent Variable CLT (DCLT), which, under certain conditions of the correlation between the variables, assures me that I should have a normal distribution when $N→∞$.

I am struggling to find any DCLT, as there are so many versions (too many numerical ones), which assures that for a big number of variables the distribution become normal.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Here is fairly general result (i.e. it holds for many types of dependent processes) :  https://www.minet.uni-jena.de/preprints/neumann_10/CLT_10_05_2010.pdf